# input type="file" is not clickable and has red "no" symbol over it in chrome

Tags: html

This is a very odd problem. I have the following HTML:

```html
    <html> 
    <body>
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </form> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Yet when I hover my mouse over the field it changes the pointer to a red "no" symbol (like a no smoking sign with no cigarette) and won't allow any interaction with the field, browse for file button, or submit button.

Chrome is Version 37.0.2062.124 m.

This code is also acting on that input field, to complete the picture.

```
//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
    ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
```

Comment: Is this absolutely the markup that causes the issue?  No other code, CSS, anything else?

Comment: You'll see I've added some code there.

Comment: The Stack Snippet you provided is working fine for me. Is it possible you have `disabled` at the end of your `input` tag, which isn't included in your question? Or possibly some third-party software installed on your machine? (I don't know of any, but I wouldn't be surprised if something existed)

Comment: The code you added won't impact the HTML though, that's all server-side code.  I agree with @MikeK, something else is up.